# SBC that interfaces with firewire and ethernet

Tags: pci-express, firewire, single-board

I have been looking around for a single board computer that can pull in information from a 6-pin firewire device, use Linux to do some computation on that incoming data, and then send information out using an ethernet port.

So far, my research has been futile. The closest I came was the Hummingboard; it has an ethernet port, can run Linux, and has a mini PCIe slot. There are mini PCIe firewire cards out there, so I thought that might work. However, the Hummingboard only has a half-length mini PCIe slot, and this won't work with any firewire cards.

Are there any SBCs out there that meet these requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so if anyone else is curious, I ended up choosing an Intel NUC to do the job. Specifically, I chose this model:
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-d34010wykh.html

Someone has already connected a firewire card to this NUC before using the NUC's mini PCIe slot. More details can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/a/vanderbilt.edu/document/d/1alWSZZ8tLYe4I-lmdrsAGT67xV77q4F4jivGeEzIklk/edit

Comment: Thanks for posting! What was your experience with it and what OS did you use?